# ComboBox Event not Comming

Tags: silverlight

I am using silverlight. I have problem that added "ComboBox" on simple Silverlight Page. But there is no event for ComboBox.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question.  What do you mean by 'no event for ComboBox'?  Can you provide some source code and/or XAML for your Silverlight page?

Comment: -1: Why on Earth did this get an up-vote? It is barely understandable let alone "useful and clear".

Comment: I simply drag and drop ComboBox on my silverlight page but in properties window there is no "event" action. But when I am doing same thing on Child Window page then events coming on Child Window page's ComboBox....

Comment: @HiTechMagic Because there are badges to be gained by giving certain number of votes on questions, and it costs rep to give downvotes...

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you've added a ComboBox element in XAML, and are looking for a SelectionChanged event in code behind.

If so, try this:

Add the SelectionChanged attribute to your ComboBox like this:

```
    <ComboBox SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged">
    </ComboBox>
```

Then go into your codebehind (F7 if you are in XAML view) and add the following inside your page class:

```
    private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

That should get you started.  Past that I would take some time to go through a few beginner complete Silverlight tutorials -- this should help familiarize you with both visual studio and the structure of a Silverlgiht app.

Comment: There is no "event" action in properties window!

Comment: Why does the properties window matter?  You really need to post more information if you're having a highly specific problem.  If you just want to get a selection changed event firing -- then just run through the steps in my answer above and it should work fine.